# Is expected that tests that works on chrome, fails on firefox?

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io, codeceptjs

I have a test that pass on chrome, but fails on firefox.

Here the test:

```
Scenario.only('Test', (I) => {

    I.see('token')
    I.click('.fa-edit')
    I.wait(1)
    I.fillField('input.EditableTitle__input','enkot')

    I.see('enkot'); fails here
});
```

The input has the value 'token' already.
Using pause(), i saw that the field is not been filled in firefox, it just erase the actual value after losing focus.
In chrome it works normally

- Codeceptjs 1.4.3
- webdriverio 4.13.2
- selenium 6.15.3
- firefox 62.0.3

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: Thanks Bill, updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue about your problem at CodeceptJs as a [fillFilled work on chrome, not on firefox](https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/518). It looks like it is a Firefox issue and it works well on selenium 3.4.0 and geckodriver 0.18.0

Comment: Tried older versions and it works for some steps. But others steps that works on news versions started to fails.